# Is horizontal size class still compact for iPhone 7 Plus on landscape?

Tags: ios, xcode, size-classes, adaptive-layout

As per references like [this](http://sizeclasses.com/) or [this](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/size-classes/), I take that iPhone 7 Plus on landscape should have regular size class.

This is the code in the current view controller, as per [this reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitenvironment/1623516-traitcollectiondidchange):

```
- (void) traitCollectionDidChange: (UITraitCollection *) previousTraitCollection {
    [super traitCollectionDidChange: previousTraitCollection];
    NSLog(@"current trait collection: %@",self.traitCollection);
    NSLog(@"previous trait collection: %@", previousTraitCollection);
}
```

And this is the output on the console when going from portrait to landscape on iPhone 7 Plus:

```
current trait collection: <UITraitCollection: 0x1c44efd00; _UITraitNameUserInterfaceIdiom = Phone, _UITraitNameDisplayScale = 3.000000, _UITraitNameDisplayGamut = P3, _UITraitNameHorizontalSizeClass = Compact, _UITraitNameVerticalSizeClass = Compact, _UITraitNameTouchLevel = 0, _UITraitNameInteractionModel = 1, _UITraitNameUserInterfaceStyle = 1, _UITraitNameUserInterfaceLayoutDirection = 0, _UITraitNameForceTouchCapability = 2, _UITraitNamePreferredContentSizeCategory = UICTContentSizeCategoryL, _UITraitNameDisplayCornerRadius = 0.000000>
previous trait collection: <UITraitCollection: 0x1c02fa900; _UITraitNameUserInterfaceIdiom = Phone, _UITraitNameDisplayScale = 3.000000, _UITraitNameDisplayGamut = P3, _UITraitNameHorizontalSizeClass = Compact, _UITraitNameVerticalSizeClass = Regular, _UITraitNameTouchLevel = 0, _UITraitNameInteractionModel = 1, _UITraitNameUserInterfaceStyle = 1, _UITraitNameUserInterfaceLayoutDirection = 0, _UITraitNameForceTouchCapability = 2, _UITraitNamePreferredContentSizeCategory = UICTContentSizeCategoryL, _UITraitNameDisplayCornerRadius = 0.000000>
```

The horizontal size class remains compact and I expected change from compact to regular.

Using iOS 11.1.2 and Xcode 9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have display zoom turned on for the device?

https://help.apple.com/iphone/11/#/iphd6804774e

In "Standard" mode, the horizontal size class in landscape will be Regular.  In "Zoomed" mode, it will be Compact.